# Encapsulating thread creation in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, design-patterns

I am relatively new to multi threaded applications.  In the past I have managed to do all the threading I need using asynchronous processing and also the Background Worker thread.

I am looking at an application that has references to Threading all over the place making it difficult to read and maintain.

Are there any design patterns that suggest ways of encapsulating all the threading? By encapsulating the threading I mean putting all the code in one place.

For example, I use to support an application that created Database Transactions all over the place.  Then I discovered the UnitOfWork pattern (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html), which allows you to encapsulate the transactions in an application.  Is there a similar way to do this for Threading?

Also I am wandering if all threads should be created in the user interface layer.  The application I am looking at seems to create threads in the business logic layer as well.

Comment: sounds ugly...  would need to know more... what are you trying to do?  are there problems?  One issue with threading is basic thread safety, I need to understand what is threaded and what you are trying to do.  Are you just trying to clean up?  The new TPL namespace is very good and efficient for multi-threaded coding.

Comment: This may be a messy application, or it may be lack of knowledge and experience on your side, or both. I would suggest you start with reading, e.g. http://www.albahari.com/threading/threading.pdf. And then use TPL and PLinq to abstract away as much as you can (but not more).

Comment: Once, an application fell into my hands. There were 15 timers running and doing stuff - that was ugly multi-threading application. I think, between `Background Worker` and `Task`, you have mechanisms to deal with threading. These are in fact your "wrappers" so you don't need to use `thread` object or `asynchronous delegates`. You need to approach each particular problem in your system and decide on the threading mechanism. Sometimes spinning a new thread is just what you need, other times you need Bg Worker to report progress, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to implement Threads. You can find useful information here:

- [Task Parallelism (Task Parallel Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)
- [Data Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

How to implement them or the software pattern that could be more useful to your application I think it will depend on the architecture and technologies used in your application.
As far as I know there isn't a single way to build applications that uses threads.